# Проверка на выход с голосового канала Discord

Tags: python, бот, discord

Вопрос такой, как добавить в бота Discord(написан на Python) проверку на выход из голосового канала? Бью с этим день, запутался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При выходе, выводит "0"

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
        print('0')
```